# Проблемы с расширением модели User

Tags: python, django

На сайте есть возможность добавить аккаунт (в данном случае аккаунт инстаграма)

**models.py**

```
class InstAcc(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                null=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    login_inst = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password_inst = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    follower_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    following_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.user.username
```

Расширил модель User, но теперь на форме появилось поле User, обязательное для заполнения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как сделать, чтобы в нем по дефолту устанавливалось значение залогиненного пользователя?

**forms.py**

```
class FormInstAcc(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InstAcc
        exclude = [""]
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-85 p-r-85 p-t-55 p-b-55">

                <form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <input class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" value="Добавить">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: прикрепите код формы и темплейта

Comment: @5c0rp, прикрепил

Comment: можно исключить из формы `user` и уже при валидации либо сохранении извлечь его через `request.user` и добавить в объект

Comment: @5c0rp, спасибо большое) всё получилось)